# Finding an irreducible region of a space given a group of transformations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, mp.mathematical-physics, solid-state-physics

Given some $d$ dimensional torus, (i.e. just a $d$-dimensional hypercube with periodic boundary conditions) I'll call $\Omega$, and a group of transformations $G$ of $\Omega$, I want to find the smallest sub-region in the hyper-torus such that the rest of the torus can be generated by the action of the group elements of $G$.

That is, I want to find the smallest $\tilde{\Omega}$ such that

\begin{equation}
\Omega = \bigcup_{g \in G} g (\tilde{\Omega})
\end{equation}

Condensed matter physicists approach this problem quite often in finding an irreducible Brillouin zone, but I cannot find any general procedure for solving this problem that doesn't involve just guessing the solution.

Does anyone have suggestions for how to go about doing this, or references they can point me to?

---

There is a related and unanswered question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284436/algebraic-determination-of-asymmetric-unit-aka-irreducible-wedge-in-brillouin

Comment: Are you familiar with Voronoi tilings?

Comment: After reading the Wikipedia page, yes I think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $G$ acts isometrically on the flat torus $T^n$. Then the standard construction of $\tilde\Omega$  proceeds as follows. Pick a point $x\in T^n$ not fixed by any $g\in G$ and consider its $G$-orbit $Gx= \{gx: g\in G\}$. Take the Voronoi tiling of $T^n$ corresponding to this subset, let $D_x$ be the tile "centered" at $x$:
$$
D_x=\{y\in T^n: \forall G \setminus \{1\}, d(x,y)\le d(gx,y)\}. 
$$
(Here $d$ is the distance function on the torus corresponding to the flat Riemannian metric.) This will be your $\tilde\Omega$. Indeed, since $gD_x= D_{gx}$, $G$ will permute simply-transitively the tiles $D_{gx}, g\in G$.

It is a nice exercise to prove that if $E\subset D_g$ is a subset whose closure is not the entire $D_x$, then $GE\ne T^n$, where
$$
GE= \bigcup_{g\in G} gE. 
$$

Comment: That is a beautiful technique, thank you! If you're interested, I put a bounty on essentially the same question on Math Stack Exchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284436/algebraic-determination-of-asymmetric-unit-aka-irreducible-wedge-in-brillouin. If you also submit your answer there, you should be able to claim the bounty.

Comment: Is there a generalization of this which doesn't assume that $G$ acts isometrically?

Comment: @Mason: Yes, but you need some assumptions on the action of $G$: $G$ is finite and acts simplicially (preserves some triangulation). See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3047013/cut-and-glue-technique-for-higher-dimensional-complexes/3054509#3054509

Comment: I've been trying to understand your link but I think I'm still confused. Are you saying that if G is finite and acts simplicially, then the Voronoi technique above is still valid? Or are you saying that your link shows a more general method different from Voronoi?

Comment: Also, do you have any guidance on how I can tell if a given group will act simplicially?

Comment: @Mason: No, in the simplicial case one uses a different construction (via a maximal subtree in the dual graph). It is not more general than Voronoi, just different. As for guidance, it depends on how your manifold and the action is given. Maybe your manifold is given by its triangulation? In general, finding an invariant triangulation is not easy and most arguments would yield an invariant metric and a Voronoi tiling as well.